# Querying a list of strings with a query string?

Tags: c#, string, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
<string,List<string>>
```

The key is the product code say "product1" then the list is a list of properties:

```
"Brand","10.40","64","red","S"
```

Then I 'can' have a list of rules/filters e.g.

```
var tmpFilter = new customfilters();
tmpFilter.Field = "2";
tmpFilter.Expression = ">";
tmpFilter.Filter = "10";
```

So for the above example this would pass because at index 2 (tmpFilter.Field) it is more than 10; then I have another object which defines which fields within the list I want to write to file. For that dictionary item I just want to write the product brand and price where the filters match.

At the moment without the filter I have:

```
var tmp = new custom();
tmp.Columns = "0,1";
tmp.Delimiter = ",";
tmp.Extention = ".csv";
tmp.CustomFilters = new List<customfilters>() {new customfilters(){ Field = "2", Expression = ">", Filter = "10"} };

public static void Custom(custom custom)
{
  foreach (var x in Settings.Prods)
  {
    //Get Current Product Code
    var curprod = Settings.ProductInformation[x];// the dictionary value

    foreach (var column in custom.Columns)
    {
      var curVal = curprod[Convert.ToInt32(column)];
      tsw.Write(curVal + custom.Delimiter);
    }
    Settings.Lines++;
    tsw.WriteLine();
  }
  tsw.Close();
}
```

I only want to write the curprod if all the filters pass for that list of strings.

How I can do this?

Comment: Do you already have the `customFilter` logic working? How are you actually applying them to your list of properties?

Comment: im not applying the filter logic at the moment that is the question how can i apply the filter logic when chosing which "products" to write to file the customfilters object just defines the filter which is a field within the custom object see my update

Comment: Still not entirely clear which part you are stuck on. Are you asking how to pick only the items that pass the filter (in which case you could simple say `if (applyMyFilters(curprod))` where `applyMyFilters` is a function that will apply each of your filters to the `List<string>` you pass it and return true or false) or are you asking how to actually use the custom filter itself? In other words, in your example how to make `tmpFilter` actually test the third item in your list with the condition `>10`?

Comment: how can i actually apply the test from a string so i can do something like curprod[0].SomeMethordToQuery("> 10") which returns a bool

Comment: Ok - so what you are actually looking for is how to parse `> 10` into an actual logical predicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a really nice Nuget package based on an example published by Microsoft, that they have decided to make really hard to find for some reason, that allows dynamic linq queries:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/1.0.2

Source:

https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic

Using that you can do stuff like this very easily (note: I used strings here because the OP states they have a `List<string>`):

```
List<string> stuff = new List<string> { "10.40", "64", "5", "56", "99", "2" };

var selected = stuff.Select(s => new { d = double.Parse(s) }).Where("d > 10");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", selected.Select(s => s.d.ToString()).ToArray()));
```

Outputs:

```
10.4, 64, 56, 99
```

That may give you a place to start. One thing you are going to have to tackle is identifying which of your fields are numeric and should be converted to a numeric type before trying to apply your filter. Otherwise you are going to comparing as strings.